# assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have set up the following struct:

```
typedef struct _thread_node_t {
    pthread_t thread;
    struct thread_node_t *next;
} thread_node_t;
```

... and then I have defined:

```
// create thread to for incoming connection
thread_node_t *thread_node = (thread_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(thread_node_t));
pthread_create(&(thread_node->thread), NULL, client_thread, &csFD);

thread_node->next = thread_arr; // assignment from incompatible pointer type

thread_arr = thread_node;
```

where thread_arr is `thread_node_t *thread_arr = NULL;`

I don't understand why the compiler is complaining. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't `struct thread_node_t *next;` be `struct _thread_node_t *next;`

---

Also, do away with the *explicit* cast.

```
thread_node_t *thread_node = (thread_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(thread_node_t));
```

#### to

```
thread_node_t *thread_node = malloc(sizeof(thread_node_t));
```

Comment: OMG! Yeah... thanks. I can't believe I missed that. I had a struct like this working in a previous program and I was killing myself because I couldn't figure it out. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: About the explicit cast: No need for ANSI C, but required for C++.

Comment: Or for that matter, `thread_node_t *thread_node = malloc(sizeof *thread_node);`.

Comment: @Macmade: I'm not wholly decided whether to cast the result of `malloc` or not, but one of the things that swings it is that as you say, if you leave out the cast it won't compile as C++. I consider this a good reason to leave out the cast!

Answer (score 3):

It's because thread_arr is a thread_node_t pointer, and your next member is a **struct** thread_node_t pointer. Not the same thing.

Comment: What I'm trying to work out, is what *is* a `struct thread_node_t`? Why does the questioner's typedef compile?

Comment: Oh, I get it, it's a forward declaration of an incomplete type.